# Finding rational solutions for a 7th degree polynomial

Tags: calculus, polynomials

This question is part of the optional section of my coursework. I was wondering if someone could help me with this problem.

I am required to find the rational solutions to the equation $7x^7 + 4x^4 +x = 5$.

For $x>0$, $f(x)=7x^7 + 4x^4 +x - 5$ is a monotically increasing function. $f(0)$ is negative and $f(1)$ is positive. Therefore, there is one root between $0$ and $1$, but I can't seem to find the exact solution.

Is there any other method I can use to solve this equation?

Comment: Use the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: Well... rational root test. You have $8$ candidates since the first and last coefficients are prime.

Comment: By differentiating the function, I’ve verified that the root is between 0 and 1. So with the rational root theorem, there are 2 candidates, 1/7 and 5/7. Unfortunately, both don’t satisfy the equation. Is there any other method?

Comment: If none of the possible cases satisfied the equation, does it mean that the root between 0 and 1 is irrational?

Comment: @tia1802 Yes, that follows from the rational root theorem.